# Converting VB.NET base64 conversion code into Java equivalent

Tags: java, android, vb.net

I am having trouble with converting some VB.NET code to Java. The conversion results are not the same for the same input file.

VB.NET

```
Using BinaryFile As FileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim BinRead As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(BinaryFile)
    Dim BinBytes As Byte() = BinRead.ReadBytes(CInt(BinaryFile.Length))
    Dim results as String = Convert.ToBase64String(BinBytes)
    BinaryFile.Close()
End Using
```

Java (Android)

```
File file =  new File( "/sdcard/a.jpg" ) ;  
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
String result = Base64.encodeToString(fileData, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: It's probably an **encoding** issue. Make sure that both methods use the Unicode **UTF-8** encoding.

Comment: Yea, you was right and also I was not reading it into a stream. Thanks